# pyspark: how to select two queries in dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I built a dataframe in pyspark and now I want to select the value of two columns. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
df.where((df['E'] ==0 ).where(df['C']=='non'))
```

Thanks

Comment: You have incorrectly placed brackets: `df.where(df['E'] ==0 ).where(df['C']=='non')`

Answer (score 4):

You use `&` (and) logic operator for this:

```
df.where((df['E'] == 0) & (df['C'] == 'non'))
```

Comment: thanks, what is the equivalent of this in sql like query?

Comment: Possibly `df.registerTempTable('temp'); spark.sql("select * from temp where E=0 and C='non'")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either where or filter -

```
df.where((df.E == 0) & (df.C == 'non'))

##OR

df.filter((df.E == 0) & (df.C == 'non'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql syntax directly:

```
df.where("E=0 and C='non'")
```